# Calculated date column based on choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I have calculated column and another column named "Project status", which the latter is of the type "Choice".

What I want to do is when Project status is changed to "Finished", the calculated column will generate the date for when the value "Finished" is chosen. I would want this date to be fixed as well, so it hopefully could be used in a Power Automate Flow later on.

Any help would be appreciated as. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve this using calculated column, you will have to use power automate flow only.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, using Power Automate, here's how you can set it up:

1. Create a new column of type `Date and Time` called `Finish Date` or any name you prefer.
2. Create a new Power Automate flow in the Power Automate portal.
3. Set the trigger to `When an item is created or modified` for the SharePoint list where the columns reside.
4. Add a condition to check if the value of the `Project Status` column is equal to `Finished`. You can use the 'Condition' action in Power Automate to achieve this.
5. If the condition is true, add an action to update the `Finish Date` column. You can use the 'Update item' action to update the corresponding item in the SharePoint list.
6. Set the value of the `Finish Date` column to the current date and time using the expression `utcNow()`.
7. Save and test the Power Automate flow.

Now, whenever the `Project Status` column is changed to `"inished` for an item, the Power Automate flow will automatically update the "Finish Date" column with the current date and time.

Once the `Finish Date` column is populated, you can use it in your calculated column or anywhere else to perform actions based on that date.

Comment: @Erocsh & Pradip, beware of infinite loop flow runs while using such flows. Also, with this approach, finish date will keep updating every time item is updated after project status is set to Finished, date will not be "fixed" as OP wanted.

Comment: I agree with @GaneshSanap's suggestion, which means you may need to include an additional condition to prevent an infinite loop in the flow and terminate it appropriately. The concept behind this approach is straightforward, aimed at providing you with a starting point for addressing your question.